# Odin not working - Samsung S3 Mini GT-I8200

Tags: odin, samsung-galaxy-s-3-mini

I tried to flash I8200XXUAPB1_I8200OXXAPC1_I8200XXUAPC1_HOME.tar.md 5 from Sammobile on Odin latest version and it failed... I also tried to reinstall the drivers, reboot PC and I also tried other odin versions like : 3.7 3.9 , 3.10 but still... no luck.
So I need help here

Screenshot :
[image: Screenshot odin_failed]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you only tried the md5 file ... An md5 is a calculation of the size the rom is, This is so you can check if you have downloaded the full rom or just half of it..

I suggest you try to flash the actual TAR file, Then the program will read the md5 to see if it's a complete rom ...

If it calculated that the md5 is "lets say" 500001 and the md5 file you downloaded says the md5 is 500002 ..

it can see that the rom is not complete or either it's not an original rom with the value of 500001